# Using an Action without an Object

Tags: facebook, action

This would defeat the whole purpose of actions but what I have is an online food menu app and all I want to do is post `username` placed an order at `app_name (restaurant name)`. With an action I could post `username` ordered a `cheeseburger` at `app_name` but that just starts getting creepy.

Comment: what is your action and what is your object? its hard to understand with out that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create an action as "place" and object as "order"

Comment: Ok so now my recent activity says `user name placed og:title at app name` my activity states how I want it to `username placed an order at app name`. My `Action` is `place` my `object` is `order`

Comment: you can simply set og:title as "order". Facebook will prepend "an" to it

Comment: that will change the title in the activity view also, but I guess it's better than the alternative.